# Bind mousewheel to two canvas but only one works

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, tkinter, widget

I try to bind the mousewheel to a scroll canvas in two frames. But I can not get it right! Only in one frame the mousewheel is bound correctly.

Where did I make the mistake? Is it not common to give every, let me call is CustomWidget and own binding to the MouseWheel?

Do I have to unbind it in any way? If yes how can I unbind it from my "MyFirstGUI" Class ? I have some troubles to find the right "self".

The binding in general is working for one class. If I scroll my mousewheel while SystemsGUI is shown in my window MainGUI gets scrolled.

Here is an extraction of my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class MyFirstGUI(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

        self.gui_control = ttk.Notebook(master)

        self.main_gui = ttk.Frame(self.gui_control, borderwidth=0) 
        self.systems_gui = ttk.Frame(self.gui_control, borderwidth=0)

        self.gui_control.add(self.main_gui, text='Main') 
        self.gui_control.add(self.systems_gui, text='Systems')

        self.gui_control.grid(column=1,row=1, columnspan=9, rowspan=50,sticky=N+E+S+W)  

        self.test_1 = Main.MainFrame(self.main_gui)
        self.test_1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="NESW") 

        self.test_2 = Systems.SystemFrame(self.systems_gui)
        self.test_2.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="NESW") 

        #[...]

master.mainloop()
```

MainGUI:

```
class MainFrame(tk.Frame):    

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)        

        self.main_canvas = tk.Canvas(self, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
        self.main_canvas.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky="NESW")  

        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self.main_canvas.yview)
        self.vsb.grid(row=0,column=1, sticky="NS") 

        self.main_canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", self._on_mousewheel)

    def _on_mousewheel(self, event):
        self.main_canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1*(event.delta/120)), "units")

    #[...]
```

Systems GUI (basically the same):

```
class SystemFrame(tk.Frame):    

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)        

        self.system_canvas = tk.Canvas(self, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
        self.system_canvas.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky="NESW")  

        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self.system_canvas.yview)
        self.vsb.grid(row=0,column=1, sticky="NS") 

        self.system_canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", self._on_mousewheel)

    def _on_mousewheel(self, event):
        self.system_canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1*(event.delta/120)), "units")

    #[...]
```

Comment: you shouldn't use `bind_all`, `bind` works in instances of a widget which is what you want, `bind_class` works on all instances of a class and `bind_all` works everywhere in your app

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately when I use bind_class both canvas wont scroll anymore.

Comment: i specifically told you that you should be using `bind` i put the rest there to explain why they are different.

Comment: Why are you defining 2 identical classes? You should define 1 class, and create 2 instances of it.

Comment: Same result with bind. Only if I use bind_all one works. I don't get it. There has to be another mistake anywhere.

Comment: @PM2Ring : in my full code they are different. I just deleted all the Entrys, Labels etc, because I am quite sure they don't have something to do with my problem/mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a full fledged example using your code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class MainFrame(tk.Frame):    

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)        

        self.main_canvas = tk.Canvas(self, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
        self.main_canvas.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky="NESW")  

        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self.main_canvas.yview)
        self.vsb.grid(row=0,column=1, sticky="NS") 

        # must configure canvas to update scrollbar when scrolled
        self.main_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)

        # add some content so can see scrolling
        self.main_canvas.create_line(0,0,200,500, fill='red')

        # tell canvas the scrollable region (used bbox(tk.ALL) to get everything)
        self.main_canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.main_canvas.bbox(tk.ALL))

        self.main_canvas.bind("<MouseWheel>", self._on_mousewheel)
        self.main_canvas.bind("<Button-4>", self._onmousewheel)
        self.main_canvas.bind("<Button-5>", self._onmousewheel)

    def _on_mousewheel(self, event):
        if event.num == 4 or event.delta == 120:
            self.main_canvas.yview_scroll(-1, "units")
        elif event.num == 5 or event.delta == -120:
            self.main_canvas.yview_scroll(1, "units")

class SystemFrame(tk.Frame):    

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)        

        self.system_canvas = tk.Canvas(self, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
        self.system_canvas.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky="NESW")  

        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self.system_canvas.yview)
        self.vsb.grid(row=0,column=1, sticky="NS") 

        self.system_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)

        self.system_canvas.create_line(0,0,200,500, fill='red')
        self.system_canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.system_canvas.bbox(tk.ALL))

        self.system_canvas.bind("<MouseWheel>", self._on_mousewheel)
        self.system_canvas.bind("<Button-4>", self._onmousewheel)
        self.system_canvas.bind("<Button-5>", self._onmousewheel)

    def _on_mousewheel(self, event):
        if event.num == 4 or event.delta == 120:
            self.system_canvas.yview_scroll(-1, "units")
        elif event.num == 5 or event.delta == -120:
            self.system_canvas.yview_scroll(1, "units")

class MyFirstGUI(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

        self.gui_control = ttk.Notebook(master)

        self.main_gui = ttk.Frame(self.gui_control, borderwidth=0) 
        self.systems_gui = ttk.Frame(self.gui_control, borderwidth=0)

        self.gui_control.add(self.main_gui, text='Main') 
        self.gui_control.add(self.systems_gui, text='Systems')

        self.gui_control.grid(column=1,row=1, columnspan=9, rowspan=50,sticky=tk.N+tk.E+tk.S+tk.W)  

        self.test_1 = MainFrame(self.main_gui)
        self.test_1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="NESW") 

        self.test_2 = SystemFrame(self.systems_gui)
        self.test_2.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="NESW") 

master = tk.Tk()
gui = MyFirstGUI(master)
master.mainloop()
```

note that i have added calls to tell the canvas's to update the scrollbars (you had only told the scrollbars to update the canvas)
and i also added a call telling the canvas which region is scrollable, if you make any changes/add widgets that change the area you want visible you'll need to update this again (every time the inner contents change size)
I also added some content so you could see the scrolling

Comment: Looks good to me, but I can't test it properly, since I run Linux which doesn't support `<MouseWheel>`, we have to use `<Button-4>` and `<Button-5>`.

Comment: I got it now. To my shame it is really a problem with all the widgets placed on that canvas. If I give that canvas a background color I see that it is only a small stripe on the side of my frame. Should I now bind all childs of System GUI and Main GUI to the mousewheel?

Comment: are you ultimately looking for a scrollable frame? if so i can save you some trouble: https://github.com/JamesGKent/python-tkwidgets/blob/master/scrolledframe.py

Comment: Somehow, but mainly learn and understand the basics . Thanks for your help!

Comment: ok, if which case what you really want is to put your widgets into a frame, that frame into a canvas and that canvas plus a scrollbar into a container widget (like a frame or a window) you bind the mousewheel onto the frame and canvas, and link the scrollbar and canvas to each other, hope that helps

Comment: @JamesKent sry for the delay. But i took a look into your github link. I have a few questions. What is "__all__ = ['ScrolledFrame']" doing? And if I import your class into a new file (just a new empty window) how do i place it on my grid?

Comment: @K-Doe go ahead, if its anything in depth probably better to ask as an issue on the github repo?

Comment: I hit return way to early and you are freaking fast :D My question is above your post!

Comment: ahhh thats an easy one, when writing a python module you can control what names get exported, if the `__all__` dict doesn't exist then all names are available for export, if it does then only names that are in the dict can be exported/imported into your script

Comment: and you literally treat it like any other frame, so: `root = tk.Tk();f=ScrolledFrame(root);f.pack();for i in range(0, 100):tk.Label(f, text=str(i)).grid(column=1, row=i);root.mainloop()`

Comment: Great i got it know! I tried to change the border of the canvas to see better where it ends for testing. I change it in: `self.canvas = tk.Canvas(
            self.outer_frame, bd=2, highlightthickness=2,[...]` but it doesnt work? Am i at the wrong row? Changeing the Background color would also work.

Comment: Because canvas doesn't normally have a border of any kind, you need to set the thickness and the style, you need to add something like relief='sunken' aswell, because of how its written the frame will always cover the entire canvas inner, so changing bg colour will be hidden by the frame

Comment: Got it. Last question for today (i hope): I added `self.vsb.grid(**self.vsb.opts)` directly in the init method but the scrollbar doesnt show up? What is my mistake there?

Comment: If you added it before the call to `self._showscrollbars()` then it would get removed again, if you create it with `scrollbars='x'` then it will always have the vertical scrollbars

Comment: I tried it both ways. To add `scrollbars='x'` before `self._showscrollbars()` and to set `self._showscrollbars()` to comment and directly add it via `self.vsb.grid(**self.vsb.opts)`. Both ways failed.

Comment: Did you add it to the constructor: `... = ScrolledFrame(root, scrollbars='x')` or in the `__init__` method? If in the method you'll need to prefix it with `self.`

Comment: I added it to the `__init__` method like `self._scrollbars="x"`. But now i added it to the constructor and it is working well. Thank you! In the meantime i tested a bit further. But i cant figure out how to set the size of the frame properly. I also tried to make it sticky to my window so it will resize properly if i change th size of my window but it also failed.

Comment: How are you putting the frame into the parent widget? If using pack you'll need to call `pack_propagate(True)` on the parent and `pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)` on the frame, if using grid youll need to configure the row and column to expand `grid_columnconfigure(col, weight=1)` and `grid_rowconfigure(row, weight=1)` on the parent and `grid(col, row, sticky='nesw')` on the frame

Comment: I use grid and now it is working perfectly well! I also tried to add more than one of your Frames to my window. Also working perfectly. Thank you very much for your help and your patience!

Comment: @JamesKent : Today I tried to change the background color of the Frame, but every type I know to do that failes. Where in your code do I have to set the background color? You said to frame covers the canvas, so I tried to change the color of the frame, is that correct?

Comment: thats my mistake, at line 54 to 58 there is a dict, this should also contain `'configure'` and then you can use frame.configure as you would any other frame. you can still pass it in to the constructor at present

Comment: I added `,'configure` to the dict 'attr' and my constructor is looking like this: `f = ScrolledFrame(master, scrollbars="y", bg="green")` but sadly no green background. Do I have to do anything else?

Comment: Got it! Forget what I wrote. Many thanks for your help!